# Matlab second y-axis label does not have the same "padding" as the first

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I made a plot and wanted to add a second y-axis with different units of measurement.

Here is what I did:

```
...
...

plot(x,y,x,y1,x,y2)
ax1=gca;
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick').'))
legend('0.5 atm','1  atm','2  atm','Location','best')
title('H_2S equilibrium partial pressure for different total pressures')
xlabel('Temperature (K)')
ylabel('Partial pressure (Pa)')
hold on
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none');
ax2.YLim = [0 0.25];
ax2.XTick = [];
ylabel(ax2,'Partial pressure (atm)') % label right y-axis
```

Here is the result:
[image]

How do I get the right label to have the same padding between itself and the edge of the figure as the left label and border?

(view the picture on a dark background to see what I mean)

Comment: How about saving to pdf (by which I mean saving with epsc, then using `epstopdf`), then using `pdfcrop`? At least if you have `pdfjam` installed.

Comment: I have never heard of any of the things you just mentioned (well, except for PDF :-P), but I can give it a go

Comment: If you have linux, it's no effort at all. I don't know about other OSes... I realize I wasn't clear: what I mentioned were external utilities.

Comment: Jip, I realized that they are external utilities. Just never heard of them. I also do not have Linux

Comment: Great, I was worried I wasn't clear:) [`pdfjam`](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) is strongly related to LaTeX, but now it seems to me that so is `epstopdf`. So it should not be a problem to install it if you have LaTeX (you might already have them installed). There are [other ways](http://superuser.com/questions/599666/how-to-convert-eps-to-pdf-in-windows) as well to convert the eps to pdf. And anyway matlab can save to pdf directly, but I've found it to do a much worse job than the eps->pdf way.

Comment: Just to be completely clear: `pdfcrop` will cut **all** whitespace from around your figure, finding the smallest bounding box for it. I assume your goal is to center the figure. Anyway, you can always add back symmetric whitespace after cropping.

Comment: @Mierzen Try manually reducing the third value (corresponding to width) of the `Position` property of both axes

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I've just now discovered export_fig. It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just discovered [export_fig](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/).

It automatically crops extra space from plots and also adds nifty features, such as anti-aliasing!